# Hide queryParams in browser URL Angular 2+ Router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am migrating my app from AngularJS 1.x to Angular2+, and i can't really get how to pass parameters between routes without having them displayed on browser URL.

In fact, using

`router.navigate(['myroute'], { queryParams: { parameter: 1 } });`

changes my url to something like

`http://localhost:81/myroute?parameter=1`.

How can i keep the url address to just `http://localhost:81/myroute` passing the parameters i need? 
Bear in mind this was definitively possible using [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/).

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure of the use case here. If the url is not expected to hold those parameters you could just store them in a service. Then you could use a resolve guard (https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) to fetch those parameters from the service and have them available for you in your routes component. The component could also pull the parameters from the service directly

Comment: Actually, i know i could use a service to store parameters between routes, but i feel like it's a less elegant approach.
In ui-router, a transition between states with parameters can happen with ease https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go.
Why angular2 doesn't offer such functionality?